# how to run my python code on google cloud without fear of getting disconnected - an absolute beginner?

Tags: python, cloud-computing

I have been trying to use python 3 for text mining on a 650 MB csv file, which my computer was not powerful enough to do. My second solution was to reach out to google cloud. I have set up my VMs and my jupyter notebook on google cloud, and it works perfectly well. The problem, however, is that I am in constant fear of getting disconnected. As a matter of fact, my connection with google server was lost a couple of time and so was my whole work.

My question: Is there a way to have the cloud run my code without fear of getting disconnected? I need to be able to have access to my csv file and also the output file.

I know there is more than one way and have read a lot of material but they are too technical for a beginner like me to understand.

UPDATE: here is how I get access to my jupyter notebook on google cloud:
1- I run my instance on google cloud
2-I click on SSH 
3- in the window that appears, I type the following:

`jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser &`

I have seen people recommend to add `nohup` to the beginning of the same commend. I have tried it and got this message:

`nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'`

And nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options to keep your session running on the host machine even if it's disconnected, see for instance this: https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/

Personally I use the `screen` command because I'm familiar with it but I think `tmux` is more recent.